# Converting object into time

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, code-analyst

I have a database that I made the difference between two dates, then I changed the format to be like : HH:MM:SS.

df['start']   type:      datetime64[ns]
df['end']   type datetime64[ns]

df['time'] = df['end'] - df['start']

**df['time']  = type:  timesdelta64**

Then

> def formatehours(interval):
> seconds  = interval.total_seconds()
>
> duration  = dt.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(seconds) formatted =
> duration.strftime('%M:%S')
>
> return '%02d:%s' % (seconds / (60 * 60), formatted)

So:

**df['time'] = df['time'].apply(formatehours)**

**df['time']  = type:  object**

df['time']:

02:19:36
08:56:46
01:59:51

I need to calculate the median of this duration, but I can't because it's an object after it's been formatted.

Comment: how is your database? you probably can substract the adjacent entries to get each delta. If you are using something like created_at = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), default=datetime.datetime.now()), then you can get delta in seconds like this timedata = int(datetime_delta.total_seconds())

Comment: df['start'] type: datetime64[ns] df['end'] type datetime64[ns]

df['time'] = df['end']- df['start']

df['time'] = type: timesdelta64

Then

def formatehours(interval): seconds = interval.total_seconds()

duration = dt.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(seconds) formatted = duration.strftime('%M:%S')

return '%02d:%s' % (seconds / (60 * 60), formatted)

So:

df['time'] = df['time'].apply(formatehours)

df['time'] = type: object

df['time']:

02:19:36 
08:56:46 
01:59:51 

Now, I wanna do a groupby then .median()

Comment: Please **format** your code blocks appropriately, and do **not** post code in the comments!